# How to force CVS to check-in code comment in particular format

Tags: eclipse, cvs

I would like to implement standard comment format for "Enter a comment for the commit operation." into CVS code repository while code check-in from eclipse or any other IDE. This should force all the users to enter comment as per standard format.

[image]

I configured one comment template but it's optional not forceful.

Example: UserName-WorkRequest#/Ticket#-Description

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to acheive this using verifymsg file.
Here is a [link](http://docs.freebsd.org/info/cvs/cvs.info.verifymsg.html)

In essence, you create a custom script to verify the log message and return with exit 0 if it passes, otherwise return exit 1
Commit will fail if it doesn't pass verifymsg script.